Problems programming ATMEL 2560
I am trying to program an ATMEL 2560 using Windows 10 (home).  I have downloaded XLOADER for WIN 10 and the download goes fine, and so does the installation process. But when I doubleclick on the XÆOADER.EXE absolutely NOTHING happens. The cursor changes to a rotating circle (indicating tha Win 10 tries to load XLOADER (I suppose) ), but after a short time it resumes to the know arrow. And NO Xloader. The ATMEL 2560 is connected to a USB-port (eg. COM 3). I have absolute no idea what is wrong. Please help. Thanks for any advise.
snestrup2016

"absolutely NOTHING happens" or "The cursor changes to a rotating circle"? This two statements are contradictory. It's either one or the other.

Yes, you are right,  The two statements are contradictory. What I maent was; XLOADER  does not start,

Don't run executables clicking them. Open a console and call them, this way if the exe prints some error you will see it in the console. I don't know what this xLoader is. Is it an official Atmel software? What kind of board are you using to program the microcontroller?

XLOADER is a program that can program an ATMEL MCU directly using the actual *.HEX file. (Intel HEX format) .  It is a "kind of replacement" for ATMEL STUDIO X ISP programming or the ARDUINO IDE.  The advantage using the XLOADER is, that you can "burn" the flash-memory in the ATMEL MCU directly (avoiding the ISP-programmer in ATMEL Studio X and the ARDUINO IDE (C++ programming)  ). You can write an assembler programs, compile it (OUTSIDE Atm STu  x and teh ARDU. IDE) and then "burn" the flash memory for the resulting *,HEX file.  Assembler in ARDU IDE is pretty tedious.

I tried downloading xloader from https://github.com/binaryupdates/xLoader  opened the exe and it correctly opens a small window where you can select the Hex file, the device, the port and the baudrate. Are you sure the window is not being open? You should also see the X icon in the taskbar.  Did you unzip the whole folder, not just the exe, so the libusb0.dll library is in the same folder of the exe?  It works for me, so I cannot reproduce your problem.

Very strange...  I downloaded XLOADER from exctly the same link 2 days ago. Installed it (= unzipped it)., and try to run it, Lot of problems (as described above). Now when  I download it, unzip it. It starts and does what it is supposed to do. Strange (very !!) . Anyway 1000000000 --> 000 thanks for the help. deeply appreciate it .   If you will place it as a SOLUTION, I will reward you.
